# Getting base type in reflection for datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am working on dynamically creating datatables from my classes I have.  Basically, I am using FieldInfo and Type, and GetFields to dynamically create the datatables.  The problem is my classes use System.Nullable which datatables cannot handle.  I am trying to get the base type, and then later set the column to Nullable = true

EDIT:  To be honest I have not tried many things yet.  I am not very good with types at the moment.  My main goal is I want to get the property types of whatever object I throw to my method and create a datatable with columns names the same as my properties with the same type.  So the spot where my code fails is when its gets to myFieldInfo[i].FieldType.  This does not actually seem to return the type, but instead returns a string describing the type.  I could manually create types by analyzing the string, but I feel that is over the top for what I need to do.

EDIT:  So ignore my code I included.  MY GOAL: I want to pass an object to my method, have it dynamically get the properties, then create a datatable with columns being named the same as the properties and having the same type (or whatever type is equivalent for datatable).  It does not necessarily need to use FieldInfo, that was just my starting spot.

Here is a copy of my basic code.

```
        DataTable peopleTable = new DataTable();
        pPeople myPerson = new pPeople();

        FieldInfo[] myFieldInfo;
        Type myType = typeof(pPeople);
        myFieldInfo = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);


        for (int i = 0; i < myFieldInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            peopleTable.Columns.Add(myFieldInfo[i].Name, myFieldInfo[i].FieldType);
            peopleTable.Columns[i].AllowDBNull = true;
        }
```

EDIT: This is what my final code looks like to create the datatable.  Thanks everyone for the help;

```
        DataTable peopleTable = new DataTable();
        pPeople myPerson = new pPeople();

        FieldInfo[] myFieldInfo;
        Type myType = typeof(pPeople);
        myFieldInfo = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);



        for (int i = 0; i < myFieldInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myFieldInfo[i].FieldType) == null)
            {
                peopleTable.Columns.Add(myFieldInfo[i].Name, myFieldInfo[i].FieldType);
            }
            else
            {
                peopleTable.Columns.Add(myFieldInfo[i].Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myFieldInfo[i].FieldType));
                peopleTable.Columns[i].AllowDBNull = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! Whats your question?

Comment: what have you tried? where are you getting stuck? try updating your question to clarify specifically what your asking.  are you looking for an alternative method to System.Nullable / an alternative programming language / existing software solution?  there are plenty of people here willing to help, but stack works best when its not for asking questions like "whats 2+2" and waiting for someone to write "4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to find out non-nullable equivalent of a given nullable type ("int" out of "int?", for example). The latter is in fact

```
Nullable<int>
```

so you need to get a generic argument.
Try this:

```
typeof(int?).GetGenericArguments()
```

Comment: I don't see `int` or `int?` anywhere in his post. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I've taken int? as just an example of nullable. It is quite obvious what is he trying to do. Given field of nullable type, he needs to find non-nullable equivalent to map it to DB type. I've edited my answer, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work with using FieldInfo to get types.  as far as I know FieldInfo can't be using within typeof(...).  I am a little new with using FIeldInfo, so I may not be correctly getting the type.  Is there anyway you could show how this would work with my code solution (specifically in the peopleTable.Columns.Add(...) area or getting the type and passing it to that?)

Comment: FieldInfo.FieldType is your type. You can find out whether it is nullable or not by calling Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myFieldInfo[i].FieldType). It will return null for non-nullable types, or underlying type for nullables.